# "ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword" error while using sequence function

Tags: sequence, sqlplus, ora-00928

Sorry I am new to SQLPlus stuffs!

So here, I have a table called **iowe**, i have a four records pre-loaded into it. This is how it looks like:

```
NAME           AMOUNT Serial Number
---------- ---------- -------------
Praveen         20500             1
Roshan           5000             2
Rohit            5000             3
Shashi           8000             4
```

Until I entered these four records, I did not know about the sequence function in SQL. So I tried implying it into this table. I wanted to input a new record, say "**XXX**" in name, **500** in Amount, and using the sequence command, i wanted the "**Serial Number**" to be auto incremented.

So I created a sequence called `iowesqn`, which looks like this, when i `select * from user_sequences`:

```
SEQUENCE_NAME       MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY C O CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER
------------------ ---------- ---------- ------------ - - ---------- -----------
SQN                         1          5            2 N N          0           3
IOWESQN                     1 1.0000E+27            1 N N          0           7
```

(Please disregard the sequence `SQN`)

To insert the sequence `IOWESQN`, I used this command:

```
insert into iowe(name, amount, "Serial Number")
values('XXX', 500, iowesqn.nextval)
```

Everything works fine. The column Serial Number increments fine by 1 on every entry. However, when i try `insert into iowe ('&name', '&amount', "Serial Number") value(iowesqn.nextval));`, it asks me fr the name, and the amount but right then (after the amount is input), it throws an error. It reads:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

This is whole thing that comes up after the amount it input:

```
old   1: insert into iowe ('&name', '&amount', "Serial Number") value(iowesqn.nextval))
new   1: insert into iowe ('ret', 'ert', "Serial Number") value(iowesqn.nextval))
insert into iowe ('ret', 'ert', "Serial Number") value(iowesqn.nextval))


ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Please tell me what I am (or (highly unlikely) it is) doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statement is wrong. Simple as that. With this fixed statement:

> insert into iowe(name, amount, "Serial Number") values('XXX', 500, iowesqn.nextval)

You probably meant to replace your values by variables, not your fields?

> insert into iowe(name, amount, "Serial Number") values('&name', &amount, iowesqn.nextval)

Comment: Sweet! It worked like a charm! It there a way to delete or change the LAST_NUMBER column in user_sequences for the sequence IOWESQN to anything else? Say 6?

It is at 11 now. 

Is that even possible? Do you want me to ask this question in a new post?

Comment: If I remember correctly you cannot reset this number. You can however, recreate the sequence with (for example) 6 as new starting value.

Answer (score 4):

I just found another case where I get "missing SELECT keyword".  I tried to insert with the column names in quotes, like this:

insert into subscription ('SUBSCRIPTION_ID','SUBSCRIPTION_NAME','CREATED_DATE') values ('558768','','20-JAN-20 10.37.47.901000000 PM');

Once I removed the quotes around the column names, it worked:

insert into subscription (SUBSCRIPTION_ID,SUBSCRIPTION_NAME,CREATED_DATE) values ('558768','','20-JAN-20 10.37.47.901000000 PM');

Comment: thank you this worked for me when using golang with godror library

Answer (score 2):

Other users may have been using `value` in stead of `values`. This is another case when you may face this problem.

Comment: And other users (such as me) may have VALUES keyword missing completely :D  Also got the same error (missing SELECT keyword).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have  missed to mention the columns list

insert into table_name(1,'alskdjflasf')

it should be like this 
insert into table_name (id,name)values(1.'lakjsdflasdf')

Answer (score -1):

JUST ADD SINGLE QUOTES IN THE COLUMN NAMES

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0O7M.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33710583)